# build function at runtime c++ from number of functions that built at compilation

Tags: c++, code-generation, bytecode

I am creating scripting language that first parse the code
and then copy functions (To execute the code) to one buffer\memory as the parsed code.

There is a way to copy function's binary code to buffer and then execute the whole buffer?
I need to execute all the functions at once to get better performance.

To understand my question to best I want to do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class RuntimeFunction; //The buffer to my runtime function

enum ByteCodeType {
    Return,
    None
};

class ByteCode {
    ByteCodeType type;
}

void ReturnRuntime() {
    return;
}

RuntimeFunction GetExecutableData(vector<ByteCode> function) {
    RuntimeFunction runtimeFunction=RuntimeFunction(sizeof(int)); //Returns int
    for (int i = 0 ; i < function.size() ; i++ ) {
        #define CurrentByteCode function[i]
        if (CurrentByteCode.Type==Return) {
            runtimeFunction.Append(&ReturnRuntime);
        } //etc.
        #undef
    }
    return runtimeFunction;
}

void* CallFunc(RuntimeFunction runtimeFunction,vector<void*> custom_parameters) {
    for (int i=custom_parameters-1;i>=0;--i) { //Invert parameters loop
        __asm {
            push custom_parameters[i]
        }
    }
    __asm {
        call runtimeFunction.pHandle
    }
}
```

Comment: Mike Pall (of LuaJIT2) comments on [implementing interpreters](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/75426) are very much worth reading.

Comment: Thanks ,but i don't need to generate code at runtime. I need to just combine some function (With const parameters too). I just don't want to meet assembly ,I hate it.

Comment: Your goals (better performance, and don't learn assembly) are mutually incompatible.  Actually, to get good performance, you'll need to go to an even lower level than assembly, and understand cache behavior, pipelining, data dependencies, etc.

Comment: I'm writing this as a comment and not as an answer because I don't think it's that constructive: Your way simply will not work. Not without using assembly code, anyway. The function `ReturnRuntime()`, for example, contains more than just the binary code for `return`. It contains the function's prologue and epilogue. It could also easily be optimized away.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think to create the 'referenced' code in C++ and then copy it ,it's  enought for me.

Comment: @Asaf Then you can trim the start and the end and copy the right code. For that ,I used labels (Start and end of code) and then I gave two pointer to copy between them ,But I have some exception ,I'll show here the code later.

Comment: @SuperFile: You can't do that with code in a finished binary.  A function isn't necessarily stored sequentially, advanced optimizers move basic blocks which are rarely used to other pages to reduce working set.  The information you need IS in the object file created by the compiler, because the linker needs it.  You'll have to start there, before the linker gets ahold of it.  But your chances of making this work without understanding assembler are poor.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways of doing this, depending on how deep you want to get into generating code at runtime, but one relatively simple way of doing it is with threaded code and a threaded code interpreter.

Basically, threaded code consists of an array of function pointers, and the interpreter goes through the array calling each pointed at function.  The tricky part is that you generally have each function return the address of array element containing a pointer to the next function to call, which allows you to implement things like branches and calls without any effort in the interpreter

Usually you use something like:

```
typedef void *(*tc_func_t)(void *, runtime_state_t *);

void *interp(tc_func_t **entry, runtime_state_t *state) {
    tc_func_t *pc = *entry;
    while (pc) pc = (*pc)(pc+1, state);
    return entry+1;
}
```

That's the entire interpreter.  `runtime_state_t` is some kind of data structure containing some runtime state (usually one or more stacks).  You call it by creating an array of `tc_func_t` function pointers and filling them in with function pointers (and possibly data), ending with a null pointer, and then call `interp` with the address of a variable containing the start of the array.  So you might have something like:

```
void *add(tc_func_t *pc, runtime_state_t *state) {
    int v1 = state->data.pop();
    int v2 = state->data.pop();
    state->data.push(v1 + v2);
    return pc; }
void *push_int(tc_func_t *pc, runtime_state_t *state) {
    state->data.push((int)*pc);
    return pc+1; }
void *print(tc_func_t *pc, runtime_state_t *state) {
    cout << state->data.pop();
    return pc; }

tc_func_t program[] = {
    (tc_func_t)push_int,
    (tc_func_t)2,
    (tc_func_t)push_int,
    (tc_func_t)2,
    (tc_func_t)add,
    (tc_func_t)print,
    0
};

void run_prgram() {
    runtime_state_t  state;
    tc_func_t *entry = program;
    interp(&entry, &state);
}
```

Calling `run_program` runs the little program that adds 2+2 and prints the result.

Now you may be confused by the slightly odd calling setup for `interp`, with an extra level of indirection on the `entry` argument.  That's so that you can use `interp` itself as a function in a threaded code array, followed by a pointer to another array, and it will do a threaded code call.

**edit**

The biggest problem with threaded code like this is related to performance -- the threaded coded interpreter is *extremely* unfriendly to branch predictors, so performance is pretty much locked at one threaded instruction call per branch misprediction recovery time.

If you want more performance, you pretty much have to go to full-on runtime code generation.  [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) provides a good, machine independent interface to doing that, along with pretty good optimizers for common platforms that will produce pretty good code at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Chris ,But it's kind of (Performance alike) my current execute way. When I parse the code ,It's gave address and one object and then push the object and call the address. BTW ,cool idea you gave here.